# Pass value from Controller to @HTML.TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a search functionality in the Index page with search options that results in Grid with Details link(another page), I am redirecting to Details page. From details page to Index page I need to retain the search criteria.

I am using ViewBag to store the values and and able to see the value in the Index.cshtml but the value is not assigned in the TextBox

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string type)
 {
    try
    {
        if (type == "Search")
        {                   
            ViewBag.Id = 100;
            return View();
        }      
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
         ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "An error occurred: " + ex.Message;
         return View();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtID", (string)ViewBag.Id, new { id = "txtID", @class = "input" })
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input class="inputBox" id="txtID" name="txtID" type="text" value="100">
```

The generated output is having the value as 100, but the value is not assigned to the Textbox and it is displaying Empty/Null.

How to assign the ViewBag value to @HTML.TextBox

Comment: I have used the suggested above and the generated html is 

<input type="text" id="txtID" name="txtID" value="100">

Still the value is not displaying in the textbox

Comment: see this example (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pyk2db)

Comment: Thank you Ajeet Kumar. your example is perfect, but still the value is not visible in the TextBox. The generated HTML is same, still the value is not being assigned to the textbox.